# Thingsboard sessionId Error in rpc getValue() reply call - Session id is not present in the metadata

Tags: thingsboard

Did everyone encounter an error in the rpc call reply node at the rule engine?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Session id is not present in the metadata
```

I use the knob widget in the dashboard but the produced rpc getValue() call to the rule engine does not have a sessionId in it. The metadata looks like that:

```
{
    "deviceName": "eui-70b3d52dd3007d4a",
    "deviceType": "vicki",
    "expirationTime": "1687854978319",
    "oneway": "false",
    "originServiceId": "tb-core-1",
    "persistent": "false",
    "requestUUID": "43c40612-9a0c-40e0-bac1-0e002b4cb247"
}
```

This is the error message I receive:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Session id is not present in the metadata!
at org.thingsboard.rule.engine.rpc.TbSendRPCReplyNode.onMsg(TbSendRPCReplyNode.java:91)
at org.thingsboard.server.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActorMessageProcessor.onRuleChainToRuleNodeMsg(RuleNodeActorMessageProcessor.java:168)
at org.thingsboard.server.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor.onRuleChainToRuleNodeMsg(RuleNodeActor.java:116)
at org.thingsboard.server.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor.doProcess(RuleNodeActor.java:75)
at org.thingsboard.server.actors.service.ContextAwareActor.process(ContextAwareActor.java:56)
at org.thingsboard.server.actors.TbActorMailbox.processMailbox(TbActorMailbox.java:170)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

I did not find anything in the documentation or in the forums so far. Perhaps somebody has a solution how to fix this issue.

Wish you all a great day.

Regards

I transformed the requestUUID and the originServiceId so that it fitts the needed format in the  rpc call reply node but I don't have any sessionId in the message given.

For everyone who has the issue with the missing serviceId this is the transormation to fix this:

```
 msg = {"targetTemperature" : metadata.targetTemperature};
 metadata.requestId = metadata.requestUUID;
 metadata.serviceId = metadata.originServiceId;
 //metadata.sessionId = "471482a4-1df5-4724-8819-18a3252ecf25";
 return {msg: msg, msgType: msgType, metadata: metadata};
```

But regarding the SessionId I have no clue yet.